Body's energy before and after thrown into space
Suppose a body is thrown out in the space with a velocity greater than its escape velocity. Now from conservation of law its said that the kinetic energy is converted to final potential energy. So that body is neither losing nor gaining any energy? But it appears that previously it was near to earth so had lesser gravitational potential energy than when it will be thrown out into the space. Plus why a photon gets redshifted if it goes out of a potential well?
So whats happening to energy of the body ?

If a body of mass at is lifted from the Earth's surface, it gains potential energy. As a projectile with some velocity goes up, it slows down losing kinetic energy, the total energy, potential + kinetic, is conserved for the whole closed system, the object and the Earth considered together.

It is slowing down so when it has a potential of energy of $U_{o}$ its kinetic energy $\Delta K_{o}=-U_{O}$

But its total energy is still same right? So the body isnt losing energy, or is it?

Yes the object's energy is the same.If you found this answer useful feel free to accept it.And if you have any more questions I will answer back even if they will be post-accept.
